# Loops of intersection number $\geq 1$ in orientable surface of genus $2$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've been studying for a topology exam and recently came across this problem which have no idea how to solve.

Let $\Sigma$ be an orientable closed surface of genus $2$. Fix a base point $x_0\in \Sigma$ and an isomorphism
$$
\pi_1(\Sigma,x_0)\cong\langle a,b,c,d \ |\ aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}=1\rangle.
$$
Since $\Sigma$ is path connected there is a standard procedure for associating to any oriented loop $\gamma\in \Sigma$ (which may or may not pass though $x_0$) a conjugacy class $C_{\gamma}\subseteq\pi_1(\Sigma,x_0)$. This I understand.

Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are oriented loops in $\Sigma$ such that $C_{\alpha}$ is represented by the element $ab^2cda^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}d^{-1}$ and $C_{\beta}$ is represented by the element $a^2bcda^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}d^{-1}$. Show that it is impossible to use homotopies of loops to make $\alpha$ and $\beta$ disjoint.

Comment: Hint: Think of homology classes.

Comment: Hi thank you yes, a friend told me about a result from intersection theory which solved the problem. The result is Theorem 11.10 from Chapter 6 of Bredon's Algebraic Topology.